# How to pass monthly subscription data to GA4

Tags: analytics, subscription, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I have a website where user purchases a book and along with that he can subscribe to monthly membership of forum. I am running paid ads to acquire customers. How can I pass monthly data to GA4 every month for subscription value so that I can see LTV (Life Time Vallue) per customer from a specific campaign?

I understand we can use Measurement Protocol (MP) API and pass user_id for specific user. But MP API need session_id and client_id. I read somewhere online it should not be more than 3 days old.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

first way is forgetting session_id and send only cid (user_pseudo_id), this causes many (not set) in session scope reports in GA4, but you can still check user ltv using uid or cid in explorer and bigquery.

the second way is sending data during a session age (the maximum session timeout is 8 hours) and MP only accepts timestamps that occur current day, Even though MP documentation claims a 3-day backdating capability, my practical tests reveal that events timestamped before 00:00 of the current day are excluded from GA4 data. (My GA4 is set to the UTC timezone, and results might differ when working with other timezones.)